# How to reduce a polynomial to $2$ real polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Can somebody explain me the principle and to show it on this example how to find $2$ real polynomials that their multiply is $p(x)$:
$$p(x)=x^{4}+1$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$x^4+1=(x^2+i)(x^2-i)=\left(x-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)\left(x-\frac{-1-i}{\sqrt2}\right)
\left(x-\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)\left(x-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt2}\right)
$$

You can see that there are two conjugate pairs (they must be so, since the overall product is a real polynomial), i.e. $\left(x-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right),\left(x-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt2}\right)$ and $\left(x-\frac{-1-i}{\sqrt2}\right),\left(x-\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)$. You then multiply the pair to get $(x^2-\sqrt2 x+1)$ and $(x^2+\sqrt2 x+1)$. So 
$$
x^4+1=(x^2-\sqrt2 x+1)(x^2+\sqrt2 x+1)
$$

In conclusion, you $1^{st}$ factorize a polynomial into its complex monomial, then multiply each complex conjugate pair to obtain real polynomial with degree at most 2. This work for any polynomial with real coefficients.

Answer (score 9):

$$x^4+1=(x^2+1)^2-2x^2=(x^2+1)^2-(\sqrt2 x)^2=(x^2+1+\sqrt2 x)(x^2+1-\sqrt2 x)$$

Comment: This is a really nice and clean way forward!  A big +1

Answer (score 4):

We know that the $4$ roots of $-1$ are $e^{\pm i\pi/4}$ and $e^{\pm i3\pi/4}$.  Then, we can factor $x^4+1$ as

$$x^4+1=(x-e^{i\pi/4})(x-e^{-i\pi/4})(x-e^{i3\pi/4})(x-e^{-i3\pi/4})$$

Finally, multiplying the first and second terms and multiplying the third and fourth terms reveals that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{x^4+1=(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)}$$

Comment: I understood best of all the first one, because I don't know the symbolization of e as you wrote it, and also because of a little literal explanation. In any case, I'm sure that it would be useful for other eather

Comment: @Ilya.K. That's fair.  The notation is the complex exponential ([See Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Imaginary_exponents_with_base_e)).  I am happy to help further.  Please let me know.

Comment: Nice solution. +1(also for formatting).

Comment: @subhadeepdey Wow!  Thank you.  Much appreciated!

Comment: This looks so much better than my solution, truly beautiful.

Comment: @bigbearZzz Wow!  I'm not sure that that is true, but much appreciate your compliment!